# How to create a listcomp for listing non-list values and then flatten everything using itertools?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm asking you here about the issue in the title because I'm both new to Python and especially creating listcomps.

I would like to create a simple function to:

1. check if all args in `*args` are lists
2. if no then it changes a value into a list
3. flatten everything using `itertools`

Below you could find my code:

```
import itertools


def lstfunc(*args):
    lstargs = list(args)
    for i in lstargs:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            lstargs[lstargs.index(i)] = [i]
    lstargs = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lstargs))
    return lstargs


print(lstfunc([1, 2, 3], 4, 5))
```

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` (correct).

My question is how to create a listcomp from this part:

```
    for i in lstargs:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            lstargs[lstargs.index(i)] = [i]
```

I tried:

```
import itertools


def lstfunc(*args):
    lstargs = list(args)
    lstargs = [[i] for i in lstargs if not isinstance(i, list)]
    lstargs = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lstargs))
    return lstargs


print(lstfunc([1, 2, 3], 4, 5))
```

But sadly this retuns only `[4, 5]`.

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listcomp you want is:

```
lstargs = [x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in lstargs]
```

to reproduce the *whole* `list`. Your attempt just filtered out the `list`s, it didn't choose between wrapping and non-wrapping and produce both. You don't need to preconvert `args` to a `list` to be clear, so you could simplify the function to just:

```
def lstfunc(*args):
    # Save eager conversion to temp list by using genexpr instead of listcomp
    lstargs = (x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in args)  # 
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lstargs))
```

Comment: @Konrad: You're welcome. A heads up: For fully generic code, you're probably better off importing the `Iterable` ABC from `collections.abc` and changing `isinstance(x, list)` to `isinstance(x, Iterable)` (possibly `isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, (str, ByteString))` if `str`/`bytes`/`bytearray` arguments are expected, though that's pretty verbose), so you're not wrapping stuff like `tuple`, `set`, random iterators, etc. in `list`. If someone calls `lstfunc((2, 3, 5), range(3), (x ** 2 for x in [10, 11, 12]))` you probably want an output of `[2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 2, 100, 121, 144]`.

Comment: please find my answer below. What do you think? Is it a good solution or should I be aware of something potentially unwanted?

Answer (score 0):

After much pain I found in fact the most simple and pythonic solution (I guess)! I needed the function above to create a 1D list to pass it to another function. However it's not necessary. I just needed an unpacking operator:

```
def testfunc(*args):
    print(args)

testfunc(*[1, 2, 3], 4)
```

Output: `(1, 2, 3, 4)`.

This solution automatically flattens all values into a 1D pure iterable (tuple I guess).

Comment: This is why it's important to also explain your actual problem, not just a question about your attempted solution. See http://xyproblem.info

Comment: Thanks, I will now remember :).